# My python class is returning No Attribute when there is clearly one there

Tags: python, class

Here is the code, the explanation is at the bottom

```
#classing tests

class Employee(object):
    raise_amount = 1.04
    def __init__(self, name, age, pay):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.pay = pay

    def __repr__(self):
        return ("Employee: {} Age: {} Pay: {:.2f}/month".format(self.name, self.age, self.pay))

    def __str__(self):
        return ("{} is {} and gets {:,.2f} per month".format(self.name, self.age, self.pay))

    @property
    def show_pay(self):
        print ("{0} gets {1:,.2f} per month".format(self.name, self.pay))

    @property
    def pay_rise(self):
        self.pay *= self.raise_amount


class Head(Employee):
    raise_amount = 1.1
    def __init__(self, name, age, pay, employees=None):
        super().__init__(name, age, pay)
        if self.employees == None:
            self.employees = []

        else:
            self.employees = employees


    def add_employee(self, employe):
        if employe not in employees:
            self.employees.append(employe)


    def remove_employee(self, employe):
        if employe in employees:
            self.employees.remove(employe)

    @property
    def show_employees(self):
        for i in self.employees:
            print(i.name())

employee_1 = Employee("John", 55, 21377)
head1 = Head("Bob", 21, 22336)

employee_1.show_pay
employee_1.pay_rise
employee_1.show_pay

head1.show_pay
head1.pay_rise
head1.show_pay

print(head1)
print(repr(head1))
```

So this is my code,when i run it, it returns `AttributeError: type object 'Head' has no attribute 'employees`. Please help, im so confused. Please help because it worked until i added the head class with the importation of employees and it is frustrating

Comment: **All of the Code didn't format properly but it starts from `Classing Tests` and ends at print(head1) and all of the lines not in pure code, most should have a line between but because of formatting, where there is a space kind of assume there is meant to be a line unless its a string or something**

Comment: You can edit your code and fix the formatting. Just copy and paste the code into the question, select all of it and then hit the `{}` button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises in the line `if self.employees is None:` in the `__init__()` constructor.
As the exception says there is no attribute called `employees` in `self`, because you didn't define it yet, hence the error.

To check for the existence of an attribute you should instead use `hasattr`, so that the above line would become `if not hasattr(self, 'employees'):`.
With this change the code runs without problems

It is generally considered more pythonic to refactor the code in such a way as to not need to use `hasattr` or similar checks, though.

Answer (score 0):

In the class `Head` you access the attribute `self.employees` before assigning a value to it, therefore the `AttributeError`. You probably meant `employees`, the argument:

```
class Head(Employee):
    raise_amount = 1.1
    def __init__(self, name, age, pay, employees=None):
        super().init(name, age, pay)
        self.employees = [] if employees == None else employees
```